# 64 bit show stopper error for appbundle flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play-console

I am trying to publish our flutter application to the google play store and Im getting what appears to be a show stopper error...

**Error**

**This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement**

**The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 3.**

**Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. [Learn More](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)**

Does anyone know how to fix this? Im not seeing anything when I google this error. We are just trying to get a Closed Alpha test out there.

Comment: Did you read the page following the "Learn more" link? It should contain all the information you need.

Comment: Yes I’ve tried every suggestion I can find .. same error occurs

Comment: That learn more section is not flutter based info

Comment: So what ABIs do you have in your APK? Do you use ndkFilters?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally fix this by adding this to build.gradle

```
  ndk {
        abiFilters  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
    }
}

splits {
    abi {
        include  "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
    }
 }
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "arm64-v8a":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: No actually it was on a post on this site from a few months ago